# Is there any sort of ways to actually prevent "crash" on missing images. (windows form application c#)

Tags: c#, image, styling

So. i recently just started with the whole windows form application c# part.

My question is. is there any neat ways to prevent the program from crashing, if a image is missing?.

Currently i'm making a small program of my own, where people have the possibility to change the look of the application (only by images for now). In case someone forgets to "re-add" the image, it would be nice to have it still working, whitout crashing due to lacking the image.

(new to stackoverflow, so i have no idea if this is the correct place).

Thank you for your time and hopefully this made sense. otherwise, i'll try explaining it differently.

Comment: try catch the exception and have a default for missing images

Comment: i used that on a foreach, just to check some xml stuff.. however, i'm not sure if it would actually work properly for images, neither do i know how to set the image to "none" - "null", in case the image is not found.

Comment: Use a default image. Or store the last user selected image too. Use that (last/default) if the current one is missing.

Comment: what do you exactly mean. andrei.ciprian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this (probably more :) )the first one is to check if the image exists, if you are getting the image from your hard drive

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\img.jpg"))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

the other way is to use try-catch block to catch the error

```
try
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\img.jpg");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

There are probably other ways you can do this but i think those two are the easiest.

Comment: Corrected. Also, I would suggest using *both*. When you know that certain error conditions may exist and you know how to handle them without further user input, it's good to avoid exception handling. It's also good to have exception handling in place to report unexpected errors (for example, the file exists, but you don't have permission to read it) to the user.

Comment: "File" does not exist in this context. that's what it says. try-catch should work fairly well on the overall thing, but i'm curious about that file thing now o_o

Comment: completely forgot about the "using part". so i managed it to "load it properly". i'll set this respond as answer. thank you everyone :)